# Envelopes not getting pulled in certain time

Tags: timezone, docusignapi

We are pulling the envelops using REST API for a particular date. It works fine, but noticed that some envelopes are not getting pulled.If there are envelopes submitted around 12 am ( we have a team in India, who submit at their time), those are not showing up.

Today got same issue and when i checked the server , it showed 4 envelopes submitted & completed between 12 am to 6 :45 am. The one's submitted fro m12 am - 3 am didnt show up at all while we used REST API.

But the 6:45 one came up . I know REST API uses GMT timezone, but since we are using only date as the criteria it should pull at some point, right?

Not sure if I am missing anything. Can anyone please help on this?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to show some code if you would like help here.  We cannot envision your implementation from the description alone.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes as Matt mentioned you should show the relevant code.  I might also suggest that you contact DocuSign support on this...

Comment: If this is still an issue, what timezone are you referring to?

Comment: Regarding this statement, "I know REST API uses GMT timezone", there is a self-service account setting which actually lets you specify the "API Timezone". Please make sure that matches your expectations.  I would agree w/the comments above, we need to see the URL used in the query since your criteria may only be asking for 'envelopes created on day X', as opposed to 'envelopes which had activity on day X'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, this issue was resolved. 
Recommend using the new v2.1 API and read all about retrieving envelopes here: 
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search